# Add new Column in table with jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi there I need your help, I have this blade on larevel :

```
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-12 col-xs-2">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-flat btn-primary btn-sm" id="add_column" title="@lang('buttons.add_new_option')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 <table class="optionsForm" style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                  <th> 
                    </th>  @for($c = 1; $c<=4; $c++)
                      <th>   
                        <input type="text" name="options{{ $c }}" value="{{ old('options.'.$c) }}" 
                        class="form-control" placeholder="Column {{ $c }} "> 
                    </th>
                    @endfor
                  </tr>  


                  @for($r = 1; $r <=4; $r++)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                          <input type="text" name="match{{ $r}}" value="{{ old('match.'.$r) }}"  
                                 class="form-control" placeholder="Row {{ $r }} ">
                        <td>
                          <input type="radio" name="col_nr[{{ $r  }}]" value="1" class="col1">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <input type="radio" name="col_nr[{{ $r  }}]" value="2" class="col2">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <input type="radio" name="col_nr[{{ $r  }}]"  value="3" class="col3">
                        </td> 
                        <td>
                          <input type="radio" name="col_nr[{{ $r  }}]" value="4" class="col4">
                        </td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="row_col_nr[{{$r}}]" value="0" class="row_col_nr{{ $r  }}">

                  </tr>
                @endfor
                <tr> 
                </tr>
              </table> 
         <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                            <div class=" col-xs-3">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-flat btn-primary btn-sm" id="add_option" title="@lang('buttons.add_new_option')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The view is a like a table..
And on the other hand my js code is this which I am using two buttons add_option and add column since the add row it was easier I managed to solve that but with adding column I have a problem:

```
<script>
var i = 4;
  var p = 1;
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add_option').click(function () {
      i++;
      $('.optionsForm').append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="match'+ i +'" value="{{ old('match. + p +') }}"  class="form-control" placeholder="Row ' + i +' "><td><input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ i +']"  value="1" class="col1" ></td><td><input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ i +']" value="2" class="col1" ></td><td><input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ i +']"   value="3" class="col1" ></td><td><input type="radio" name="col_nr['+ i+']"value="4" class="col1" ></td></tr>');

    }
    );
    $(document).on('click', 'button[id=delete_option]', function () {
      console.log('test');
      if (i > 1) {
        var removeValue = $(this).val();
        $('#option' + removeValue).remove();
        --i;
      }
    }
    );
  }
  );
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 4;
  var p = 1;
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add_column').click(function () {
      i++;
      $('.optionsForm ').append('<tr></tr><tr><th><input type="text" name="options'+ i +'" value="{{ old('options. + p +') }}"  class="form-control" placeholder="Col ' + i +' "></th></tr>');

    }
    );
    $(document).on('click', 'button[id=delete_option]', function () {
      console.log('test');
      if (i > 1) {
        var removeValue = $(this).val();
        $('#option' + removeValue).remove();
        --i;
      }
    }
    );
  }
  );
</script>
```

For adding a new row it is working fine but with column I am having a problem, I cannot add the new column in the right place after the last one the radio inputs are not in the right place.. Can someone please help me.

Comment: For adding new column, you have to append a new `<th>` to first row and appending a new `<td>` to all other rows.

Comment: Can you please give an example where to put them..

Answer (score 0):

try this code as you would like

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>tiff.js demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 
$(".get_attr").click(function (){
 var trow;//=$('.optionsForm tr:first').html();
 trow='<th>Class</th>';
 $('.optionsForm tr:first').append(trow);
 var tdr={};//=$('.optionsForm tr:first').html();
 tdr=['<td>sdg</td>','<td>sdfg</td>','<td>sdgds</td>'];
 var rowleng=$('.optionsForm tbody tr').length;
 for(i=0;i<=rowleng;i++)
     {
   $('.optionsForm tbody tr').eq(i).append(tdr[i]);
  
  }
   });

});
    </script>
  </body>
  
<table border="1" class='optionsForm'>
  <thead><tr><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td>sdg</td></tr>
  <tr><td>sdfg</td></tr>
  <tr><td>sdgds</td></tr>
  </tbody>
 
  
  </table>
  
  <button type="button" data-id="5" class="get_attr" >Click Me</button>
  
</html>
```

also added row column value in respective cloumn

Comment: Thanks but this works only with the head I want also to add all tht othe sdg  the entire colon